# ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting model to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got RobertaForSequenceClassification

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model, huggingface

I am training a text classification model using RoBERTa. (https://huggingface.co/siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english)
I use google colab for running the code.
I am facing a valueError i have trid googling about this error and i have not gotten a solution and i have also tried using other pretrained models in hugging face but I face the same error in all the models.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english")
train_encodings = tokenizer(X_train, truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(X_test, truncation=True, padding=True) 
training_args=TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=2,
   per_device_train_batch_size=8, # batch size per device during training
   per_device_eval_batch_size=16, # batch size for evaluation
   warmup_steps=500,
   weight_decay=0.01,
   logging_dir='./logs',
   logging_steps=10,
)  
with training_args.strategy.scope():
    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english")

    
trainer = TFTrainer(
    model= model,
   args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset
)
trainer.train() 

`
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-2a4521c5cd87> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py in _assert_trackable(obj, name)
   1462       obj, (base.Trackable, def_function.Function)):
   1463     raise ValueError(
-> 1464         f"`Checkpoint` was expecting {name} to be a trackable object (an "
   1465         f"object derived from `Trackable`), got {obj}. If you believe this "
   1466         "object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the "

ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting model to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got RobertaForSequenceClassification(
  (roberta): RobertaModel(
    (embeddings): RobertaEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(50265, 1024, padding_idx=1)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(514, 1024, padding_idx=1)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(1, 1024)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    )
    (encoder): RobertaEncoder(
      (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (1): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (2): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (3): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (4): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (5): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (6): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (7): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (8): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (9): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (10): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (11): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (12): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (13): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (14): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (15): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (16): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (17): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (18): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (19): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (20): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (21): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (22): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (23): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (classifier): RobertaClassificationHead(
    (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (out_proj): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=2, bias=True)
  )
). If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.`
```

Comment: Why do you use TFTrainer with pytorch?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you suggest alternative to TFTrainer please? @cronoik

Comment: The alternative is `Trainer`.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve the error? I am having the same thing with a BERT based transformer too.